# Where is Moshe in the Torah?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, chulin-tractate, agada-stories-legends

The Gemara in Chullin (137b) asks where several characters of the Megillah are found in the Torah: Esther (Devarim 31:18), Mordechai (Shemos 30:23), and Haman (Bereishis 3:11).

Then it throws a curveball: Moshe min haTorah minayan.

Where is Moshe in the Torah?! Look in [almost any parshah from Shemos to Ma'asei](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5764/moshes-name-is-missing) and you'll find his name. What does this mean, where is Moshe in the Torah? However you explain the question, how does the answer (Bereishis 6:3) answer it?

Comment: אין מקשין על האגדה

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) (there) addresses your question. He explains that it asks for a hint that references him before he came:

> ועוד זה שאלו ממנו - מנין למשה רמז קודם שבא שסופו לבא

This is clearly the understanding of the [Torat HaMinha](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99) (Parashat Shemot: derasha 20 p. 176) as well:

> ומששת ימי בראשית היתה נפשו של משה רבינו ע"ה מזומנת לבוא ולפרנס לישראל בגלות מצרים, וכמו שאמרו (חולין קלט ב) מנין למשה מן התורה דכתיב בשגם הוא בשר והיו ימיו מאה ועשרים שנה, בשגם בגמטריה משה, ורצו לומר שקודם שבא לעולם כבר היה מזומן ומוכן לבוא

The Talmud similarly asks for "sources" for Haman, Ester, and Mordekhai, although they too are explicit Biblical figures.

[Maharsha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharsha) (Hidushei Aggadot Hullin 139b) explains that the Talmud *is not* simply looking for mention of these characters. Rather he connects the passage to the fact that these four characters all had multiple names. Moshe is called Toviah, Avigdor, etc. Haman is said to be identical with Memukhan, while Ester is actually identified in Scripture as Hadassah. And, Mordekhai is identified with P'tahyah. One could therefore claim that their "real" names were something other than their popular names. In the case of Moshe, for example, it could be claimed that Pharaoh's daughter gave him an Egyptian name, and that Moshe is thus an Egyptian name. Similarly, Ester, Mordekhai, and Haman are all Persian names.

The Talmud's question, is therefore how we know that the popular names are their "primary names", alluded to in the Torah.

That being the question, the answer demonstrates that the name Moshe is used to allude to him, and is his "primary name"

---

Text of Maharsha:

משה מן התורה מנין כו' המן מן התורה כו' אסתר כו' מרדכי כו'. יראה בזה לפי שבאלו הד' מצינו שיש להם עוד שמות אחרים במשה טוביה אביגדור כו' בהמן אמרו שהוא ממוכן אסתר היא הדסה מרדכי בלשן פתחיה ולפי הנראה היה לבעל דין לחלוק ולומר **שאלו שמות המיוחדים להם אינם עיקר מן התורה בהם** כי שם משה בת פרעה נתנה לו והוא לשון מצרי כדעת המפרשים ושם המן ומרדכי ואסתר נראה כי שמות פרסיים הם כי המגילה נכתבה ע"י הפרסיים שע"כ לא הוזכר שם הקדוש ברוך הוא במגילה כדעת הראב"ע וע"כ **אמר במשה מנין שהוא שם המיוחד לו לעיקר מן התורה שנאמר בשגם הוא בשר גו' שקודם שנקרא כך ע"י בת פרעה קראו התורה אותו בשם זה** ע"ש שהוא הוציא ומשה את ישראל מן הים עד"ה ימשני ממים רבים וע"כ נקרא משה ולא נמשה או משוי והוא מבואר כשדור המבול לא היו מאמינים בהשגחה פרטית שאמרו מה שדי כי נעבדנו כדאמרי' פ' חלק ונפרע מהם במדה כי לפי הטבע ראוי שיהיה העולם מים במים אבל היתה השגחה אלהית שנא' יקוו המים ותראה היבשה לצורך בן אדם וע"כ הביא עליהם מי המבול כפי הטבע ולפי שע"י משה רבינו נתפרסם זאת השגחה שבני ישראל הלכו ביבשה תוך הים והמצריים נטבעו שם ע"כ הזכיר שם משה כאן

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara seems to not just want an appearance of a name, but how the person's name is rooted in the Torah in a way that shows on that character's essence.

Esther represents the hiding of Hashem's face so to speak (Haster, Astir), while behind the scenes He is controlling every detail. Esther experienced this walk of faith in the Purim story. Mordechai's righteousness is somehow hinted at by being part of the incense spices. Perhaps through his bitter (Mar) cries of Teshuvah, he caused freedom (Dror) for his people.  Haman who is destined to be hanged is connected in the Torah with a tree (Min HaEtz )(gallows).

**Bereishis 6:3** states:

וַיֹּאמֶר יְהֹוָה לֹא יָדוֹן רוּחִי בָאָדָם לְעֹלָם בְּשַׁגָּם הוּא בָשָׂר וְהָיוּ יָמָיו **מֵאָה וְעֶשְׂרִים שָׁנָה**

And the Lord said, "Let My spirit not quarrel forever concerning man, because he is also flesh, and his days shall be **a hundred and twenty years**."

Moshe lived 120 years. The first letter of the word "100" is "Mem". The middle letter of the word "20" is "Shin". The last letter of the word "years" is "Hey".

That spells Moshe.

(Do not be worried that the middle of "20" also contains a letter "Resh". The verse itself instructs us to skip the "Resh"! בְּשַׁגָּם הוּא בָשָׂר tells us "with the shin (use the shin only). Even though it (the word) also has two - shin and resh. - בְּשַׁ. גָּם הוּא בָ- שָׂ,ר ) :)

This may mean that all of G-d's worries about the spiritual frailty of mankind was taken care of, by the eventual service of Moshe Rabeinu, who was able to receive and teach the Torah to Israel.

I have no source, but your question got me thinking so I was inspired by it, B"H. :)

Comment: Cute. :) But ועשרים has an even number of letters, so the ר is also in the middle. Are you saying his name should be spelled משרה? ;) Of course, this still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @DonielF I edited to answer your question. Apparently, when faced with an even number of center letters, you may pick one. :) I hope that isn't too lame. :)

Comment: Hm. It still feels a little too far-fetched. Besides, it's still unsourced.

Comment: @DonielF OK, I fixed the Shin Resh problem too! I am sure that the Hastir Astir, Mar Dror, and Min HaEtz are talked about by meforshim. If I have time, maybe I can remember where. :) Nice question.