# Shiluach HaKan and Megillah Character Sources

Tags: chulin-tractate

The Gemara in Chullin (137b) asks where several characters of the Megillah are found in the Torah: Esther (Devarim 31:18), Mordechai (Shemos 30:23), and Haman (Bereishis 3:11), [as well as Moshe (Bereishis 6:3)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78717/where-is-moshe-in-the-torah).

This passage appears in the middle of a discussion of the mitzvah of Shiluach HaKan. Why does it appear here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rashi says that the previous questioner had asked "If a man had a bird nest on his head, is it obligated in shiluach hakan?" After receiving the answer from Rav Masna, he continued to ask more questions.

Apparantly after he received a good answer from Rav Masna based on a drashah of a posuk, he turned the subject to other source drashas he was interested in.

Comment: And then at the end of the mini-sugya the Gemara returned to Shiluach HaKan? I suppose that makes sense, but then why wasn't the entire sugya, including the question with the nest on his head, pushed to the end?